# Deleting rows from database based on selected checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete certain rows in my database whether if they were selected by clicking their check box. I'm using the PK, an auto incremented ID to identify which row was selected, to delete it. But i'm failing to delete it. Any help please..What's wrong with my syntax.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jr', 'root', 'Js');
    $conn->exec("set names utf8");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $num_rows = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees')->fetchColumn(); 


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT appendtest.ID,appendtest.EvaluationType,appendtest.EvaluatorAF,appendtest.EvaluatedAF FROM appendtest");
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $selectedtable = "<table class='sortable'><tr><th>Select</th><th>Evaluation Type</th><th style='width:200px'>Evaluator AFNumber</th><th style='width:150px'>Evaluated AFNumber</th></tr>\n";



    foreach($result as $row) {



        $selectedtable .= "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='del' value='$row[0]' style='margin:10px;'></td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>\n";



    }
    if(isset($_POST['del']))
            {   

                $sql="DELETE  FROM appendtest  WHERE id = '$row[0]'";
                mysqli_query($con,$sql);

         }
    $selectedtable .= "</table>\n";
         $selectedtable .= "<input type='submit' name='del' value='Delete' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>\n";
```

Comment: What do you mean by *fail to delete it*?

Comment: @D4V1D It's not working

Comment: Well, what do you mean by *it's not working*?

Comment: @D4V1D when i say i'm trying to delete and it's not working, what do you suppose it means?

Comment: For the future, when someone asks what is meant by *not working*, please post any error, what is expected and what is happening instead of replying ironically.

Comment: @D4V1D if there was an error, i would've posted it... But since the problem is that the required functionality isn't working, that's what i stated.

Comment: You seem to have a hard time getting what you should do in order to ask a good question. Please refer to [this blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (linked in the help center you *should* have read), especially the part where: "*Be detailed: in particular, if something didn’t work, don’t just state that: tell us how it failed. If it threw an exception, what was the exception?*". Thanks.

Comment: Learning how to ask a proper question will allow you to better understand what you are doing to the point that you might easily solve the issue and not need to ask the question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First, change from

```
<input type='checkbox' name='del' value='$row[0]' style='margin:10px;'>
```

To

```
<input type='checkbox' name='del[]' value='$row[0]' style='margin:10px;'>
```

And change name of submit for something else than 'del', as example 'sub'

Then change action to:

```
if ($_POST['sub'] && count($_POST['del']) > 0) {
    $ids = implode(',', $_POST['del']);
    $sql = "DELETE  FROM appendtest  WHERE id IN ('$ids')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

If you want add some security things do:

```
$ids = implode(',', array_map('intval', $_POST['del']));
```

Comment: That code is inside <form action="" method="POST"></form>?

Comment: yes it is. I'm getting undefined index for sub, though i changed the name of the submit button

Comment: You can replace 'if' with ``if(isset($_POST['del']) && count($_POST['del']) > 0)``

Comment: krivstov still nothing

Comment: any chance we can open a chat conv for a minute?

Answer (score 0):

HTML checkbox code

```
<form method="post" action="filename.php" >
<input type='checkbox' name='del[]' id='del[]' value='$row[0]' style='margin:10px;'>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $checkbox = $_POST['del'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
    {
       $id = $checkbox[$i];

       $sql1 = "DELETE  FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` =' $id' ";
       mysqli_query($con, $sql1) ;
    }
 }
```